# disable log4net logging in third party dll

Tags: logging, log4net

I am working on WPF application with log4net logging. 
Also using one third party DLL for SWF file reading purpose. 
This DLL was developed with log4net logging.

When working with swf reading functionality in my application i have  noticed that around 7MB of information logging in to my application logfile by third party dll. Because of this my application logfile size is increasing drastically.

Is there any way to disable that third party dll logging from my application configuration file? I don't have source code of this third party dll.

Answer (score 10):

Download [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Use it to determine what's the package root used by third party application. If it's `Com.Thirdparty`, then put this into your log4net configuration:

```
<logger name="Com.Thirdparty">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```